# Kafka Streams : How can you archive data which has certain ttl

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

Kafka streams provides different persistent stores, one of them being RocksDBWindowStore. So, if we set retention time it will delete the key-value pair if the retention time is crossed. Is there any callback functionality provided which we can use before deletion of this data? Usecase- I want to archive data into a distributed database before it is deleted from rocksdb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no callback.

However, all data is also written to an topic in Kafka. Thus, you can consume this topic for archive the data into a different store. The topic name will be `<application.id>-storeName-changelog`.

Comment: Thanks, @Matthias. But my understanding of changelog topic is that it is the moment of truth for this application. So, it will have all the data. I only want to archive the data which has lived for a particular time, i.e. deleted by window store.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no callback, Rocksdb is inherently a sorted db which is sorted by key. So, I used two stores, one timestamp based(kind of treemap) which contains set of keys and another original key value based. So, I could iterate over timestamp based store and archive the key-value pair from other store and then delete the keys from both the stores, which need to be archived after some particular time.